# change chart type in dimple.js to automate chart production

Tags: dimple.js

I would like to be able to change the chart type of charts using dimple.js by using a variable. I want for instance to switch from bars to lines. I've tried with no success, it seems simple however! Any idea?

Below is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var chartType = "line";
  var chartDimple = "dimple.plot." + chartType;
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.csv("data/test.csv", function (data) { //d3.tsv("data/example_data.tsv", function (data) {
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
      var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month");
      x.addOrderRule("Date");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Unit Sales");
      // myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
      myChart.addSeries(null, chartDimple);
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string to myChart.addSeries instead of a dimple.plot object. To make it dynamic you would need to reference the static object you're looking for on the dimple.plot object :

```
var chartType = "line";
var chartDimple = dimple.plot[chartType];
myChart.addSeries(null, chartDimple);
```

https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.plot#static-objects

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. However, I'm facing the same issue, for what I imagine is the same problem. I want to group my x axis through a configuration file, thus, am trying this : 'var MyGroup = ["Channel", "Month"]; var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", MyGroup);' it does work. However  when instead of setting the value of MyGroup manually, I read it from a configuration file, it does not work anymore. I don't get it. I would welcome any advice.

Comment: I would need to see the code you're using for the second example. Can you post a new question with that code and possibly create a jsbin replicating it? Probably an issue with how the file is being read in

Comment: Hello, and thank you. I've post a new question with some code on plunker. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181687/automation-of-dimple-js-charts-with-a-configuration-file